# Use django, filter and get to the same id, but result data not same, why?

Tags: django, filter, get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdPDv.png)

just like this, I guess its beacause of caches, but i don't ensure, how should i do? thanks

Comment: show me your views.py

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.